# How to write text into a file opened in binary mode using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-io, binaryfiles

I run the following code with Python 3.5.1 on Windows 7.

```
with open('foo.txt', 'wb') as f:
    print(b'foo\nbar\n', file=f)
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(b'foo\nbar\n', file=f)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

My intention is to write text in a file such that all `'\n'` appears as LF (as opposed to CRLF) in the file.

What's wrong in my code above? What is the right way to write text into a file opened in binary mode?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need binary mode. Specify the newline when opening the file. The default is universal newline mode, which translates newlines to/from the platform default. `newline=''` or `newline='\n'` specifies untranslated mode:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w', newline='\n') as f:
    print('foo', file=f)
    print('bar', file=f)

with open('bar.txt', 'w', newline='\r') as f:
    print('foo', file=f)
    print('bar', file=f)

with open('foo.txt','rb') as f:
    print(f.read())

with open('bar.txt','rb') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output (on Windows):

```
b'foo\nbar\n'
b'foo\rbar\r'
```

Comment: That is going to `CRLF` on Windows instead of writing `LF`. I want `LF` to be written even on Windows.

Comment: @LoneLearner did you try it?  Python 3 does it's own line handling and it writes only LF on Windows with this code.  I'm on Windows and verified it with a hex dump.

Comment: @LoneLearner Added proof.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you so much this really helped me :).

Answer (score 0):

`print()` does things to the object passed to it. Avoid using it for binary data.

```
f.write(b'foo\nbar\n')
```